# Azure file storage create file using shared key

Tags: azure

How to make a StringToSign for create file, tried to use the below docs but not successful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected vs actual results, etc. Right now, there's no specific question here; just links to documentation. This would imply that someone else should follow the links, read the docs, figure out a solution for you, and publish it here. Unfortunately this isn't how Stack Overflow works. We also don't know what language you're working in. And also, if you really intend to make direct REST calls (per the links you provided) or via one of the language SDKs. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and below worked with powershell

"PUT`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`nx-ms-content-length:1024`nx-ms-date:Fri, 31 Aug 2018 14:20:48 GMT`nx-ms-type:file`nx-ms-version:2018-03-28`n/storageaccountname/filesharename/filename"